# Track & field standard (400 meters) stadiums recommendations in Haifa?

Tags: israel, sport, haifa

Could you recommend any track & field standard (400 meters) stadiums in Haifa also with public access for training (free or paid)?

Would be nice to know current condition of the track (damages, possibility to run in spikes)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: @Dorothy , people have defferent needs while they are travelling. Someone needs to know the best bars, another one need places to play tennis, to run etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is *eliciting list-style answers, suggestions or recommendations on a topic or place*, which is ill-suited to the Stack Exchange Q&A format.

Comment: @Dorothy When voting to close as off-topic, please explain your reasoning.

Comment: @DavidRicherby sorry, I was just overcome and thought we were being pranked by the Ministry of Silly Walks; maybe [SE Sports](https://sports.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this 2012 Hebrew article in Haaretz](http://www.haaretz.co.il/sport/active/1.1876442), there are two options:

1. The "[Sportek](https://m.facebook.com/pages/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%A7-%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%9F-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%94/140940539369317)"  - open to public, 420 meters track, badly neglected.
2. The [Neve Shaanan stadium](http://www.ethos.co.il/%D7%90%D7%A6%D7%98%D7%93%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%94.html) , which hosts competitions, not open unless you're a member of a sports association.